# User xxx is not authorized to encrypt records in stream xxx

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kms

I want to use script to put an encrypted record on a kinesis stream. But it always show access issues.

> I am not able to PutRecord on my User XXX is not authorized to encrypt records in stream XXX.

I have been attached two policy in my IAM console:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "kinesis:PutRecord",
        "kinesis:PutRecords"
      ],
      "Resource": "some_Stream_ARN"
    }
  ]
}
```

and KMS policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I still cannot have the correct access. I have check my env's `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `SECRET`, also `~/.aws/credential` and `~/.config` to ensure I login as the correct user.

What other access policy should I attach then?

Background: MacOS, [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/boto3.html)

Comment: I had a similar issue with PUT access for different aws service, when I provided only PUT access; allowing GET access also fixed that for me.

Comment: Thanks for resp. This isn't my case though.

Answer (score 0):

What is your KMS key policy for the CMK you are using with that stream?

The IAM policy simply states whether the account admin is allowing that user/role to perform certain actions on certain resources.
For services like KMS that also have resource policies, the owner of that resource must *also* express, though the resource policy, who they are allowing to use that resource.

If you do not have something in the key policy (or a grant) that allows this user/role to use the CMK, then the IAM policy you defined does not come into play.

[See the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/policy-evaluation.html) for more information on the KMS authorization flow.

Comment: Indeed I didn't specify any CMK, if I didn't specify, KMS gonna handle it for me right? Say I don't want to separately manage CMK, that's why KMS exist right?

Comment: KMS manages the CMK for you, but you still need to manage the access policies that control *access* to the CMK. Those access policies are rooted in the KMS key policy, as described in the link in my answer.